How to Obtain Wildcard SSL Certificates for Domains with Only NS Server Access?
I'm setting up a server with Named (BIND) and Nginx, and I have a domain registered on Namecheap that serves as the nameserver domain for my setup. This domain is pointed to my server via NS records. I need to be able to quickly add new domains purchased from various platforms (like Cloudflare, Namecheap, etc.) to my server, using NS-1, NS-2, and so on.
My challenge is to obtain SSL certificates, ideally Wildcard SSL certificates, for these domains and their subdomains, but I won't have direct access to the domain provider's panel once the NS records are set. I'm aware of the DNS-01 challenge method for obtaining Wildcard SSL certificates, but it typically requires access to the DNS provider's API or panel to create the necessary TXT records.
Here are the specifics of my situation:
I have a server with Named and Nginx.
Domains point to my server using NS records.
I need to obtain Wildcard SSL certificates for these domains.
I do not have direct access to the domain provider's panel after setting the NS records.
Domains will be purchased from different providers like Cloudflare, Namecheap, etc.
I've considered using Certbot with the DNS-01 challenge, which works well for Cloudflare with an API token. However, I'm looking for a more universal solution that can handle domains from various providers without needing direct access to each provider's panel.
Has anyone faced a similar situation, and what solutions did you find effective? Are there any tools or methods that can help streamline this process?
Any advice or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated!
